# Sitecron to run alternate week

Tags: sitecron

I have a routine activity taking place at my Sitecore instance which is executed every alternate week on Thursday.

What  I have tried:

1. `0 0 12 ? * WED *` But this gets triggered every week.
2. I couldn't find a way to read the last run value in the script to be triggered, so I can read the value in the console and write the logic there.
3. I saw scripts as mentioned at https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/187347-cron-alternate-sunday.html, but such a thing won't be possible in Sitecore.
4. I cannot go by the logic of odd/even week as it can cause an issue when the year changes.

Any help or suggestion?

Comment: Any details on why alternate weeks is necessary?

Comment: @MichaelWest: We do production deployment alternate week. Before the build, we need to do an activity.

Comment: Not really possible to run with 100% accuracy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350047/how-to-instruct-cron-to-execute-a-job-every-second-week

Comment: Would seem like a better alternative is to use an external process to manage the scheduling and then trigger a process to run in Sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
0 0 1-7,15-21 * 3
```

This cron job would hit the first and third Wednesday of the month.

You can test the cron expression here:

https://crontab.guru/#0_0_1-7,15-21_*_3

Comment: I can't go with this approach. I can edit for the 1st, 3rd and 5th Wednesday of the month also. But it will then again trigger on the 1st Wednesday of the next month, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

To set up a cron expression for every alternate week on Thursday, you can use the following cron expression:

```
0 0 12 ? * THU 0/2
```

Breaking down the expression:

1. 0 0 12: At 12:00 PM.
2. ?: No specific day of the month.
3. *: Every month.
4. THU: On Thursday.
5. 0/2: Every 2 weeks.

This expression should trigger the task every alternate Thursday at 12:00 PM.